# Cities in Europe to visit during the end of October?

Tags: europe, cities

In the last week of October, I'm planning a short city trip (3-4 days) in Europe. Can you recommend a destination that is worth a visit at this time of the year? I don't care if it is not 30 degrees, but I don't want to get wet because it is raining all day.

I'm particularly interested in cities which offer a lot of sightseeing. Partying isn't very important. Additionally the countries I prefer are England, Scotland, Ireland, Spain and the Balkans.

It should also be possible to travel there from Switzerland without being too expensive.

Comment: Do you have a preference for visiting a single big city, or several smaller places in a region? Also, what kinds of things are you hoping to see/do?

Comment: You want to include everything from Iceland to Turkey to Scotland to Croatia to San Marino? You can't narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Not really, I want to include all ;)

Comment: Then I think this question is too wide open for Stack Exchange. It's subjective because what's worth visiting for one person will be different for other people. Beyond that you are asking for a list of all cities with little rain and no other preferences. Both list questions and questions without a single right answer are discouraged.

Comment: Fair enough, I edited my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sevilla should be very nice, and you can organize a trip to Cordoba and/or Granada if you wish. Note that if you want to see Alhambra in Granada you should really book tickets over Internet more than a month before travel.

Answer (score 11):

Italy in October is lovely!

Temperatures in October vary depending on where you are in Italy, but as a general rule of thumb these are the ranges:

```
Northern Italy: 45-65°F (7-18°C)
Central Italy: 55-70°F (13-21°C)
Southern Italy: 65-75°F (18-24°C)
```

Having visited Venice, Florence and Rome in October, the weather is still very comfortable...A few rain sprinkles here and there but nothing crazy. Temperature is perfect for walking around and site seeing.  There are also a number of amazing food festivals in Italy during that time!

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in Ireland I would recommend Cork or Dublin which may be the easiest to get to depending on where you are coming from.

Given the time of year however, avoiding rain might be difficult and southern Europe might be a better bet.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on where in Europe you will be, of course, and what you have seen already. I'd tend to cities at the Mediterranean at this time of the year that are protected by mountains - Barcelona is nice, Tuscany (Florence et al), Rome, or Athens.

Answer (score 3):

My top three choices for a quick trip would be (in no particular order):

1) Rome
2) Prague
3) Palermo (in Sicily - you can travel around the island easily)

Answer (score 3):

If I got a chance to make an [Europe travel](http://flybee.com) I would like to prefer visit in 1. Milan, Italy ,2. Brussels, Belgium, 3. Berlin, Germany .

Comment: Thanks, but visited all of them multiple times ;) That's why I limited the question to Great Britain, Spain and the Balkans.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Aha I think I wasn't the only one that read your qeustion as wanting places *similar to* those. I will edit your question a little.

Answer (score 3):

What about Zagreb or Ljubliana? There is a daily night train from Zurich to these places. The train goes on to Belgrade. But that will last more than 20 hours. Maybe a bit too much if you want to go on a journey for 3 or 4 days.

For [Ljubliana](http://www.slo-zeleznice.si/en/passengers/abroad/destinations/switzerland), fares start at 39 EUR, one way in a couchette.

Comment: Ljubliana I've already visited, but Zagreb is a great hint. I plan to go there this year. I also took this train for hundreds of times (ok not until the final destination), but I think it is almost cheaper and way more comfortable to fly there.

Comment: Yes, but don't forget that a night in the sleeper train can replace a night in the hotel. Moreover, if you live in or around Zurich, you can go on Friday evening to the station (rather than the pub) take the train an wake up in Zagreb, spend two full days there, and be back in Zurich on Monday morning ...

Answer (score 2):

I visited Sarajevo in Mid-october 2010, the weather was great (clear blue sky, temperature around 10°C). This is a great city if you're interested in ancient or recent history, people are very friendly there, it is very cheap, and you won't be annoyed by huge groups of tourists.

Answer (score 2):

I could recommend you visiting Sevilla-Córdoba-Granada-Málaga (Andalusia)

Sevilla http://travelinginspain.com/sevilla/sevilla.htm

Granada (Alhambra and San Nicolás viewpoint)http://travelinginspain.com/granada.htm

http://www.bed-and-breakfast-granada.com/mirador-San-Nicolas.html

Málaga http://travelinginspain.com/testweb.html

Córdoba http://travelinginspain.com/cordoba.html

The weather is sunny very often. The places to eat and drink usually are cheap (tapas) and the food is delicious and there are a wide range of accomodations.

Answer (score 2):

No mention for Oktoberfest yet? Munich has an annual beer festival if that's your thing.
Also, I don't know any but I'd be surprised if Russia didn't do something for October.
Thirdly, October is Black History Month in the UK.

HTH

Comment: Probably because the Oktoberfest does not take place at the end of Octobre.